# Generate a list of hexadecimal numbers in python

Tags: python-2.7

I'm working on  a cryptography project and I need to generate all hexadecimal possible numbers (length of the number= 16 bits in binary) and put them in a list in order to use them later.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Yet) another Python one liner :

```
a = [hex(x) for x in xrange(0,pow(2, 16))]
```

**EDIT :** Given all the comments, we now have :

```
a = map(hex, xrange(pow(2,16) - 1))
```

Comment: Shouldn't it not have the `-1` at the end since `xrange` generates up to `upperlimit-1`?

Comment: You might want to add in `map` for completeness.  `a = map(hex,xrange(pow(2,16)))`

Comment: the `0` in `xrange` should also be superfluous (`xrange` should start at `0`)

Comment: you can also use the struct or binascii libraries to translate.

Answer (score 1):

Why not generate all the integers from 0 to 2^16-1, and convert to hex? Yes, I know that it could be done more efficiently, but you are doing this ONCE. Why make things difficult?